# Global minimum and maximum defined in the square

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, maxima-minima

Given the function
$$f(x,y)={x^3-3xy+y^3-2}.$$ defined in the rectangle $[0,3] \times [0,2]$. Find the **global minimum and maximum** and at what point does it reach.

I tried finding the maximum, it is $25$ and $(3,0)$, but I am not sure. I haven't tried the minimum.

Comment: I did it and i got 25.

Comment: Wow, thanks. The global minimum is -3 in the point (1,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=x^3-3xy+3y^3-2$.

Thus, $f$ is a convex function of $x$ and $f$ is a convex function of $y$.

Since a convex function gets a maximal value for an extreme value of the variable, we obtain:
$$\max_{(x,y)\in[0,3]\times[0,2]}f=\max_{x\in\{0,3\},y\in\{0,2\}}f=f(3,0)=25.$$
Now, $f(1,1)=-3$ and by AM-GM:
$$x^3-3xy+y^3-2-(-3)=x^3+y^3+1-3xy\geq3\sqrt[3]{x^3y^3}-3xy=0,$$
which says that $-3$ is a minimal value.

Comment: Thanks! Its a great explanation. I understand now

Comment: You are welcome, @Gabriel!